# Is it possible to read in hyperspectral image file ( .bil) into C/C++ or CV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

My research involves processing huge hyperspectral image files with extention of ".bil". I am not sure if there is a toolbox to read such files in CV or C/C++.
 Does anyone know ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL libraries can handle those files.
You most likely need some meta data from individual header files (.hdr) to handle the raw data in .bil files.

- https://gdal.org/
- https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html